# Android AutoFocusCallback is not being called or not returning

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I’m developing a barcode scanning app that has the following the functionality:

•   Access device camera , preview camera on SurfaceView , and automatically refocus

•   Attemtps to decode barcode using 2 methods

a) On SurfaceView touch using **onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)**, attempts to take a picture of the barcode , but gets **java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed**

b) Or **Preferably** , can take a picture on success of  **onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)** , but onAutoFocus() does not get called

I’m implementing the **“AutoFocusCallback”** and setting back to the camera object in my scanning activity called **“ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity”.**

**Below is my “ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity”   which takes care of camera functionality:**

```
 package com.t.t.barcode;

    /* I removed import statements because of character limit*/
    import com.t.t.R;

public class ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera globalCamera;
    private int cameraId = 0;
    private TextView VINtext = null;
    private Bitmap bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = null;
    private boolean isThereACamera = false;
    private RelativeLayout RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner = null;
    private CameraPreview newCameraPreview = null;
    private SurfaceView surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = null;
    private String VIN = null; 
    private boolean  globalFocusedBefore = false;

     //This method , finds FEATURE_CAMERA, opens the camera, set parameters ,

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void initializeGlobalCamera() {

        try {
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else { // check for front camera ,and get the ID
                cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
                if (cameraId < 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "camera was found , ID: " + cameraId);
                    // camera was found , set global camera flag to true
                    isThereACamera = true;
                    // OPEN
                    globalCamera = getGlobalCamera(cameraId);
                    //PARAMETERS FOR AUTOFOCUS 
                    globalCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                    //set auto focus callback , called  when autofocus has completed
```

globalCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
                        // pass surfaceView to CameraPreview
                        newCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, globalCamera) {

```
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity"," onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) ");

                            takePicture();
                            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                        }

                    };

                    // pass CameraPreview to Layout
                    RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.addView(newCameraPreview);
                    //give reference SurfaceView to camera object 
                        globalCamera
                                .setPreviewDisplay(surfaceViewBarcodeScanner
                                        .getHolder());


                    // PREVIEW
                    globalCamera.startPreview();

                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "camera opened & previewing");
                }
            }// end else 
        }// end try
        catch (Exception exc) {

            //  resources & cleanup
            if (globalCamera != null) {
                globalCamera.stopPreview();
                globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                globalCamera.release();
                globalCamera = null;

            }
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity initializeGlobalCamera() exception:",
                    exc.getMessage());
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }// end catch

    }

    // onCreate, instantiates layouts & surfaceView used for video preview
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_vin_scanner);
        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity", "onCreate ");

        // create surfaceView for previewing 
        RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutForPreview);
        surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewBarcodeScanner);

        initializeGlobalCamera();

    }// end onCreate

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, onResume() globalCamera:",
                String.valueOf(globalCamera));

        initializeGlobalCamera();

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        if (globalCamera != null) {
            globalCamera.stopPreview();
            globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            globalCamera.release();
            globalCamera = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (globalCamera != null) {
            globalCamera.stopPreview();
            globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            globalCamera.release();
            globalCamera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }// end onPause()

    // callback used by takePicture()

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imgData, Camera camera) {
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = null ;
            try {

                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity", "onPictureTaken()");

                 // 1)down-sampled the image via to  prevent MemoryOutOfBounds exception.


                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed =true;

                bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                        imgData, 0, imgData.length, options);

                if (bmpOfTheImageFromCamera != null) {

                    // 2) Samsung galaxy S only , rotate to correct orientation 

                    Matrix rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise = new Matrix();
                    rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise.postRotate(90);

                    bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            bmpOfTheImageFromCamera, 0, 0,
                            bmpOfTheImageFromCamera.getWidth(),
                            bmpOfTheImageFromCamera.getHeight(),
                            rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise, true);

                    // 3) calculate relative x,y & width & height , because SurfaceView coordinates are different than the coordinates of the image
                    guidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations = new guidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations(
                            bmpOfTheImageFromCamera.getWidth(),
                            bmpOfTheImageFromCamera.getHeight());


                    // 4) crop & only take image/data that is within the bounding rectangle 
                    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap
                            .createBitmap(
                                    bmpOfTheImageFromCamera,
                                    newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                            .getGuidanceRectangleStartX(),
                                    newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                            .getGuidanceRectangleStartY(),
                                    newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                            .getGuidanceRectangleEndX()
                                            - newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                                    .getGuidanceRectangleStartX(),
                                    newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                            .getGuidanceRectangleEndY()
                                            - newguidanceRectangleCoordinatesCalculations
                                                    .getGuidanceRectangleStartY());



                    //Bitmap to BinaryBitmap
                    bitmap = cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap(croppedBitmap);

                    //early cleanup 
                    croppedBitmap.recycle();
                    croppedBitmap = null; 

                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        // 7) decode the VIN

                        VIN = decodeBitmapToString(bitmap);
            Log.("***ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity ,onPictureTaken(): VIN ",
                                VIN);
                        if (VIN!=null)
                        {
                            //original before sharpen
                            byte [] bytesImage = bitmapToByteArray ( croppedBitmap );
                            savePicture(bytesImage, 0 , "original");

                            //after sharpen         
                            croppedBitmap = sharpeningKernel (croppedBitmap);

                            bytesImage = bitmapToByteArray ( croppedBitmap );
                            savePicture(bytesImage, 0 , "sharpened");



                            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "VIN:"+VIN, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity ,onPictureTaken(): bitmap=",
                                String.valueOf(bitmap));

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , onPictureTaken(): bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = ",
                            String.valueOf(bmpOfTheImageFromCamera));

                }

            }// end try

            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.getMessage();

                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , scanButton.setOnClickListener(): exception = ",
                        exc.getMessage());
            }

            finally {

                // start previewing again onthe SurfaceView in case use wants to
                // take another pic/scan

                globalCamera.startPreview();
                bitmap = null; 
            }

        }// end onPictureTaken()
    };//end 
    //autoFocuscallback
    AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
              Log.d("***onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)","success: "+success); 


              if (success)
              {

                 globalFocusedBefore = true;
                  takePicture();
              }



          }
        };//end 

        public Camera getGlobalCamera(int CameraId)
        {
            if (globalCamera==null)
            {
                // OPEN
                globalCamera = Camera.open( CameraId);
            }

            return globalCamera;

        }

        /* find camera on device */
        public static int findFrontFacingCamera() {
            int cameraId = -1;
            // Search for the front facing camera
            int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
                CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
                if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , findFrontFacingCamera(): ",
                            "Camera found");
                    cameraId = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return cameraId;
        }// end findFrontFacingCamera()

    /*
     * created savePicture(byte [] data) for testing
     */
    public void savePicture(byte[] data, double sizeInPercent , String title) {
        Log.d("ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity ", "savePicture(byte [] data)");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_sample_sizePercent_" + sizeInPercent + "_" + title + "_"
                + date + ".jpg";

        File sdDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        String filename = sdDir + File.separator + photoFile;

        File pictureFile = new File(filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d("File not saved: ", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    /*
     * Attempts to decode barcode data inside the input bitmap. Uses zxing API */
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public String decodeBitmapToString(BinaryBitmap bitmap) {

        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                "decodeBitmapToString(BinaryBitmap bitmap");
        Reader reader = null;
        Result result = null;
        String textResult = null;
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = null; 

        try {

             decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
            decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
            decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);

            reader = new MultiFormatReader();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
                if (result != null) {
                    Log.d("decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): result = ",
                            String.valueOf(result));

                    Log.d("decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): result = ",
                            String.valueOf(result.getBarcodeFormat().toString()));

                    textResult = result.getText();

                } else {
                    Log.d("decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): result = ",
                            String.valueOf(result));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): bitmap = ",
                        String.valueOf(bitmap));
            }


        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            textResult = "Unable to decode. Please try again.";
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, NotFoundException:",
                    e.getMessage());

        } catch (ChecksumException e) {

            textResult = "Unable to decode. Please try again.";
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, ChecksumException:",
                    e.getMessage());

        } catch (FormatException e) {

            textResult = "Unable to decode. Please try again.";
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, FormatException:",
                    e.getMessage());

        }

        finally {
            //cleanup 
            reader = null;
            result = null;
            decodeHints = null; 
            return textResult;
        }
    }// end decodeBitmapToString ()

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public BinaryBitmap cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap (Bitmap bitmap):",
                "");
        BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = null;
        RGBLuminanceSource source = null; 
        HybridBinarizer bh = null; 
        try {

            if (bitmap != null) {                   
                //bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                //RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), pixels);

                source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap);
                 bh = new HybridBinarizer(source);

                binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(bh);

            } else {
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap (Bitmap bitmap): bitmap = ",
                        String.valueOf(bitmap));
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } finally {


         source = null; 
        bh = null;
            return binaryBitmap;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    /*
     * The method getScreenOrientation() return screen orientation either
     * landscape or portrait. IF width < height , than orientation = portrait,
     * ELSE landscape For backwards compatibility we use to methods to detect
     * the orientation. The first method is for API versions prior to 13 or
     * HONEYCOMB.
     */
    public int getScreenOrientation() {

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // if API version less than 13
        Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;

        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Do something for API version less than HONEYCOMB

            if (getOrient.getWidth() == getOrient.getHeight()) {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
            } else {
                if (getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()) {
                    orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                } else {
                    orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Do something for API version greater or equal to HONEYCOMB

            Point size = new Point();
            this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;

            if (width < height) {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        }

        return orientation;

    }// end getScreenOrientation()


    public Bitmap sharpeningKernel (Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        if (bitmap!=null)
        {

            int result = 0 ;
            int pixelAtXY = 0; 
            for (int i=0 ; i<bitmap.getWidth(); i++)
            {

                for (int j=0 ; j<bitmap.getHeight(); j++)
                {
                    //piecewise multiply with kernel
                    //add multiplication result to total / sum of kernel values 
                    /* Conceptual kernel
                     * int kernel [][]= 
                {{0,-1,0},
                {-1,5,-1},
                {0,-1,0}};
                     */
             pixelAtXY = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);

                result = ((pixelAtXY * -1) + (pixelAtXY * -1) + (pixelAtXY * 5)+ (pixelAtXY * -1)  + (pixelAtXY * -1)); 
                 bitmap.setPixel(i, j,result);
                }
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }//end 

    public byte [] bitmapToByteArray (Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                baoStream);
        return baoStream.toByteArray();
    }


        public void takePicture()
        {
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity","takePicture()");
            try {

                // if true take a picture
                if (isThereACamera) {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "setOnClickListener() isThereACamera: "
                                    + isThereACamera);

                    // set picture format to JPEG, everytime makesure JPEg
                    globalCamera.getParameters().setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

                        if ( globalFocusedBefore = true)
                        {
                    // take pic , should call Callback
                    globalCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                    //reset autofocus flag 
                     globalFocusedBefore = false; 
                        }

                }

            }// end try
            catch (Exception exc) {

                // in case of exception release resources & cleanup
                if (globalCamera != null) {
                    globalCamera.stopPreview();
                    globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    globalCamera.release();
                    globalCamera = null;

                }
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity setOnClickListener() exceprtion:",
                        exc.getMessage());
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }// end catch

        }// end takePicture()

}// end activity class
```

**Below is my preview class, which displays live images from camera**

```
package com.t.t.barcode;

/* I removed imports due to character limit on Stackoverflow*/

package com.t.t.barcode;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context context;
    //
    private int guidanceRectangleStartX;
    private int guidanceRectangleStartY;
    private int guidanceRectangleEndX;
    private int guidanceRectangleEndY;
    //
    private ImageView imageView = null; 
    private  Bitmap guidanceScannerFrame = null; 

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        this.context = context;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

          setWillNotDraw(false);
          setFocusable(true); 
          requestFocus(); 

          guidanceScannerFrame  =  getBitmapFromResourcePath("res/drawable/scanner_frame.png");

    }

    public void drawGuidance(Canvas canvas)
    {


    Paint paintRed = new Paint();
    paintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintRed.setStrokeWidth(6f);
    paintRed.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintRed.setColor(Color.RED);

    //drawMiddleline
     canvas.drawLine(0,this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()/2, paintRed);


    if (guidanceScannerFrame!=null)
    {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);


int diffInWidth =0;
int diffInHeight = 0;

try
{

diffInWidth = this.getWidth() - guidanceScannerFrame.getScaledWidth(canvas);
diffInHeight = this.getHeight() - guidanceScannerFrame.getScaledHeight(canvas);

//
    canvas.drawBitmap(guidanceScannerFrame,(diffInWidth/2),(diffInHeight/2) , paint);
}
catch (NullPointerException exc)
{
    exc.printStackTrace();
}

/*create rectangle that is relative to the SurfaceView coordinates and fits inside the Bitmap rectangle, 
 * this coordinates will later be used to crop inside of the Bitmap to take in the only the barcode's picture*/

Paint paintGray = new Paint();
paintGray.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paintGray.setStrokeWidth(2f);
paintGray.setAntiAlias(true);
paintGray.setColor(Color.GRAY);
//drawRect
canvas.drawRect((diffInWidth/2), (diffInHeight/2), (diffInWidth/2)+guidanceScannerFrame.getScaledWidth(canvas),(diffInHeight/2)+guidanceScannerFrame.getScaledHeight(canvas), paintGray);


this.guidanceRectangleStartX = this.getWidth()/12;
this.guidanceRectangleStartY=  this.getHeight()/3;
this.guidanceRectangleEndX = this.getWidth()-this.getWidth()/12;
this.guidanceRectangleEndY =(this.getHeight()/3)+( 2 *(this.getHeight()/3));
    }

    }

      @Override 
      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 

          //drawGuidance
          drawGuidance(canvas);



      } 


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {

            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

            // get width & height of the SurfaceView
            int SurfaceViewWidth = this.getWidth();
            int SurfaceViewHeight = this.getHeight();

            List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, SurfaceViewWidth, SurfaceViewHeight);


            // set parameters
            p.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
            p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            /*rotate the image by 90 degrees clockwise , in order to correctly displayed the image , images seem to be -90 degrees (counter clockwise) rotated 
             * I even tried setting it to  p.setRotation(0); , but still no effect.
             */
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();


        } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }


        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CameraPreview ,  surfaceCreated() , orientation: ",
                    String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }// end surfaceChanged()


     static Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List <Camera.Size>sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            final double MAX_DOWNSIZE = 1.5;

            double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
            if (sizes == null) return null;

            Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
              double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
              double downsize = (double) size.width / w;
              if (downsize > MAX_DOWNSIZE) {
                //if the preview is a lot larger than our display surface ignore it
                //reason - on some phones there is not enough heap available to show the larger preview sizes
                continue;
              }
              if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
              if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
              }
            }
            // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
            //keep the max_downsize requirement
            if (optimalSize == null) {
              minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
              for (Size size : sizes) {
                double downsize = (double) size.width / w;
                if (downsize > MAX_DOWNSIZE) {
                  continue;
                }
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                  optimalSize = size;
                  minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
              }
            }
            //everything else failed, just take the closest match
            if (optimalSize == null) {
              minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
              for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                  optimalSize = size;
                  minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
              }
            }
            return optimalSize;
          }


     public Bitmap getBitmapFromResourcePath (String path)
     {
         InputStream in =null;
         Bitmap guidanceBitmap = null;

         try
         {
         if (path!=null)
         {

          in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);

          guidanceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

         }
         }
         catch (Exception exc)
         {
             exc.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally
         {
             if (in!=null)
             {
                 try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         }
         return guidanceBitmap;
     }

    public int getGuidanceRectangleStartX() {
        return guidanceRectangleStartX;
    }


    public int getGuidanceRectangleStartY() {
        return guidanceRectangleStartY;
    }


    public int getGuidanceRectangleEndX() {
        return guidanceRectangleEndX;
    }

    public int getGuidanceRectangleEndY() {
        return guidanceRectangleEndY;
    }


}//end preview class
```

**Screenshot activity GUI:**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated , Thanks.

Comment: Please check your camera has auto Focus functionality..

Comment: Did u mention all required permissions in Manifest?

Comment: @SweetWisher , yes the required permissions are in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` , The actual problem is that the onAutoFocus() does no return or get called, although I actually see the autofocus functionality working in my app. I cant call the takePicture method from inside onAutoFocus().

Comment: @Ciril , yes my device the Galaxy S3 has autofocus ,and my app actually autofocuses but the AutoFocusCallback seems to never return, I cant get  below code to execute : 
          
`public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
              Log.d("onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)","success: "+success); 
              
//I acnt call the takePicture from inside onAutoFocus() althought this method works when called from a button's onlick method            
takePicture();
  

          }
        };//end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are calling autofocus on Oncreate in preview class
it should be called at surface created or surface changed
since autofocus occurs once the camerapreview has been started
have a look on this code i have worked on this and it is working

```
private void tryAutoFocus() {
    if( MyDebug.LOG )
        Log.d(TAG, "tryAutoFocus");
    if( camera == null ) {
        if( MyDebug.LOG )
            Log.d(TAG, "no camera");
    }
    else if( !this.has_surface ) {
        if( MyDebug.LOG )
            Log.d(TAG, "preview surface not yet available");
    }
    else if( !this.is_preview_started ) {
        if( MyDebug.LOG )
            Log.d(TAG, "preview not yet started");
    }
    else if( is_taking_photo ) {
        if( MyDebug.LOG )
            Log.d(TAG, "currently taking a photo");
    }
    else {
        // if a focus area is set, we always call autofocus even if it isn't supported, so we get the focus box
        // otherwise, it's only worth doing it when autofocus has an effect (i.e., auto or macro mode)
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        String focus_mode = parameters.getFocusMode();
        if( has_focus_area || focus_mode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO) || focus_mode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO) ) {
            if( MyDebug.LOG )
                Log.d(TAG, "try to start autofocus");
            Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    if( MyDebug.LOG )
                        Log.d(TAG, "autofocus complete: " + success);
                    focus_success = success ? FOCUS_SUCCESS : FOCUS_FAILED;
                    focus_complete_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if(_automationStarted){
                        takeSnapPhoto();
                    }
                }
            };
            this.focus_success = FOCUS_WAITING;
            this.focus_complete_time = -1;
            camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if( MyDebug.LOG )
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated()");
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
    this.has_surface = true;
    this.openCamera(false); // if setting up for the first time, we wait until the surfaceChanged call to start the preview
    this.setWillNotDraw(false); // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687015/extended-surfaceviews-ondraw-method-never-called
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if( MyDebug.LOG )
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed()");
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    this.has_surface = false;
    this.closeCamera();
}
public void takeSnapPhoto() {
    camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
            //YUV formats require more conversion
            if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
                int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
                // Get the YuV image
                YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, format, w, h, null);
                // Convert YuV to Jpeg
                Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
                ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, output_stream);
                byte[] byt = output_stream.toByteArray();
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    // Write to SD Card
                    File file = createFileInSDCard(FOLDER_PATH, "Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
                    //Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outStream.write(byt);
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

when you initialize camera(or open camera in this case)

```
 private void openCamera(boolean start_preview) {
      tryautofocus();//call this after setting camera parameters 
        }
```

Comment: I used your guideline and moved the autofocus to the SurfaceView's onSurfaceChnaged(), which now takes pictures , but only after I touch the screen onTouch. So it works well onTouch & after onTouch, but still does not fire onFocus. I tried calling onFocus in the surfaceCreated but than the app crashes, I think because the Preview has not started. I will update the code above with the correct recommendation & when the bugs are out soon. Anyways your code helped me in about 90% of the problem.

Comment: Aryan if you want to capture pictures you can call takeSnapPhoto() on button click also but if you need more clear image you can use tryautofocus() before takeSnapPhoto() also..

Comment: nive, thanks for clearing up that camera.autofocus() has to be called AFTER camera.startPreview()

Answer (score -1):

You could just use override of the Camera.AutoFocusCallback interface. Or try to make "autoFocusCallback" varialbe static. It would help.

Comment: I'm already overriding the onAutoFocus() of the AutoFocusCallback class, and passing that to the Camera, you can see this in the "ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity" class above. There is no advantage in making the object static, or overriding the entire class. `AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() { @Override public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) { if (success) { takePicture(); } } };`