# Log.v doesn't show show output for setting Camera preview and image size

Tags: android, eclipse, image, logging, android-camera

I am trying to set the camera preview size and also the image size in the Camera Preview class. But, my Log.v to show the camera preview size and image size does not display anything in the logcat. So, I have no idea whether the camera preview and image is set to the size I wanted. I am using Eclipse.

I am calling the setCamera() from the Camera Preview constructor.

```
 public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    setCamera(mCamera);
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

And my set camera has the Log.v to display the size of the preview and the image size.

```
 public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

    mCamera = camera;

    if (mCamera != null) {
        List<Size> localSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = localSizes;
        //parameters.setPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes.get(0).width, mSupportedPreviewSizes.get(0).height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        Log.v(preview, "get preview size: " + parameters.getPreviewSize() 
                + "get picture size: " +parameters.getPictureSize());
        requestLayout();


        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
          Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must 
          be started before you can take a picture.
          */
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it is working.

```
 public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "Camera Preview";
    private static final double PREVIEW_SIZE_FACTOR = 3.00;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder = null;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    Camera.Parameters _parameters=null;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            final Size mPreviewSize = getOptimalSize();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
             requestLayout();
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            //startContinuousAutoFocus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // set Camera parameters

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        }
    public void startPreview(){
        try{
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
            } 
            private Size getOptimalSize() {
        Camera.Size result = null;
        final Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Log.i(CameraPreview.class.getSimpleName(), "window width: " + getWidth() + ", height: " + getHeight());
        for (final Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= getWidth() * PREVIEW_SIZE_FACTOR && size.height <= getHeight() * PREVIEW_SIZE_FACTOR) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    final int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    final int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
        }
        Log.i(CameraPreview.class.getSimpleName(), "Using PreviewSize: " + result.width + " x " + result.height);
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print a `Camera.Size`, use `parameters.getPreviewSize().width` and `parameters.getPreviewSize().height` instead. The same for `getPictureSize()`.

Maybe the log isn't showing due to log level or tag filtered (what's the content of `preview` variable?), try changing it:

```
Log.d("CAMERA_PREVIEW", "get preview size: " 
    + parameters.getPreviewSize().height + " " 
    + parameters.getPreviewSize().width 
    + "get picture size: " 
    + parameters.getPictureSize().height + " "
    + parameters.getPictureSize().width
);
```

or even `Log.e` just for testing (it's misleading since it's not an error, but it's just for a moment, change it back later) and see if the log appears (look for "CAMERA_PREVIEW" tag).

Comment: What do you get in log? Does the text "get preview size: " appear? Or nothing at all? Are you showing verbose logs and filtering the right tag?

Comment: The text "get preview size" does not appear. I am filtering verbose messages specific to my application but only Android tags like dalvikvm, etc is appearing. I am running the application in Nexus 4.

Comment: Notice you put `Log.v(preview,…`. What does `preview` contains? Try changing it to something constant and change the log level. I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Hmmm.. still not working.. but found a workaround, just took a pic and checked out the size in gallery.